# How to remove zoomout content

Tags: html, css, grid, frontend

i have a problem with my "website" whenever i zoom-out to max, below my Box 5"footer".
there's this huge amount of white space, which i don't want.
I think i need to size my website in some sort of a way, as in giving the page a horizontal and vertical max. Unsure if that works with grid. Another solution i believe could be having box2 and 4 horizontal max and having header and footer always on sticky, and having box 3 as auto.
I've been stuck on how to solve it. Saw another post on stackoverflow on how someone solved it, however it didn't work with mine.

After i solve this then my goal is to make box 1 2,4,and 5 sticky or something similar, so it scrolls with the page. and box 3 as content.

```css
 .grid {
 display: grid;
 grid-template-columns: 1fr 4fr 1fr;
 background-color: #8b9dc3;
 height: 100vh;
}

.box1 {
  background-color: #3b5998;
  grid-column: 1/4;
  grid-row: 1/2;
  z-index: 2;
}

.box2 {
  grid-column: 1;
  /* grid-row: 2/12; */
  grid-row-start: 2;
  grid-row-end: 12;
}

.box3 {
  background-color: #ffffff;
  grid-row: 2/12;
  grid-column: auto;
}

.box4 {
  align-self: stretch;
  grid-column: 3;
  grid-row: 2/12;
  grid-row: 2 / max;
}

.box5 {
  background-color: #3b5998;
  grid-column: 1/4;
}

html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="mystylesheet2.css">
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="grid">
    <div class="box box1">box1</div>
    <div class="box box2">box2</div>
    <div class="box box3">box3</div>
    <div class="box box4">box4</div>
    <div class="box box5"> box5</div>
  </div>
</body>


</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it.

Removed `grid-auto-rows: minmax(100px, auto);`
also added the height, as i was talking about to 100vh

Didn't really understand the **auto** function. I believe it maximize the entire screen with rows.